# apache redirect to port based on the URL

Tags: apache

I have `apache web server` :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.foo.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/testApplication

  CustomLog /var/log/apache/testApplication-access.log combined
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache/testApplication-error.log

  # Example SSL configuration
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
  SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
  SSLCertificateFile "/var/www/testApplication/ssl/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/var/www/testApplication/ssl/server.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

I would like to redirect request which came to:

```
localhost:443/WebService1.php to localhost:9003/ws
localhost:443/WebService2.php to localhost:9004/ws
```

- `9004` and `9003` are ports on which `java` application is listening

I was trying to achieve it by modifying `VirtualHost` into:

ServerName www.foo.com
      DocumentRoot /var/www/testApplication

```
  CustomLog /var/log/apache/testApplication-access.log combined
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache/testApplication-error.log

  # Example SSL configuration
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
  SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
  SSLCertificateFile "/var/www/testApplication/ssl/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/var/www/testApplication/ssl/server.key"

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:9003/ws
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:9003/ws
</VirtualHost>
```

however this way everything is being redirected into `9003`. How can I modify this setting so that both `9003` and `9004` will be used?

Comment: Since you wrote "WebService1.php" I suppose you have also php available on your server, maybe this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php

Comment: @Matteo to be honest I am little ashamed I didn't figured that this is possible to do it little bit easier. thx!

Comment: @Matteo I have validated it and it is not acceptable :( this way client is being redirected, and I want to handle connection localy

Comment: I suggest you to edit your question to add this information. Then you could try mod_proxy to forward the connection http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html